# File ID output instead of URL | Suddenly ACF broke | Contact form 7 | Dynamic Text Extension

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, contact-form-7, dynamic-forms

I have a problem, it used to work great but suddenly it isn't working anymore. I hope I'll be clear.

I have a client (real estate website) and he uploads with ACF a unique pdf brochure per blogpost(listing), on the listing pages there's a CF7 and when that's filled out the customer will a unique brochure pdf URL e-mailed to them.

As a said it worked really well, but for some reason, the ACF output changed from URL to ID and I can't seem to find a reason why. So instead of a nice link, for example, [www.link.com/2021/example.pdf](http://www.link.com/2021/example.pdf) I now only get a file id like 65432 for example.

[The output is on FILE-URL in ACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeOJ3.png)

The hidden field that I use with the Dynamic Text Extension plugin:

```
[dynamichidden pdf_brochure "CF7_get_custom_field key='pdf_brochure'"]
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction or show me a different solution on how to get the dynamic pdf URLs outputted into the form submissions?

Have a nice day!

Comment: Go to the ACF group fields and find the File field. There you can change the return type of field from ID to URL again.

Comment: Like I stated in my previous post, the return type is already on url, I tried switching and switching back. Nothing happened. Still get the ID as output.